# Developer's Fundamentals 10 Collection ( Sitecore Certification )

Tags: training-certification

I am getting this error when executing

.\up.ps1

Status: pull access denied for myproject-dotnetsdk, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied, Code: 1

Where do i set the docker login ?

=============================================================

I am trying to follow steps in

Walkthrough: Using the Getting Started template

https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/101/developer-tools/walkthrough--using-the-getting-started-template.html

=============================================================

3 errors occurred:

- Status: pull access denied for myproject-dotnetsdk, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied, Code: 1
- Status: pull access denied for myproject-dotnetsdk, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied, Code: 1
- Status: pull access denied for myproject-solution, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied, Code: 1

Answer (score 2):

This is commonly because your Docker Desktop is configured to "Compose V2" mode. Open up Docker Desktop, go to "Settings" and Uncheck "Use Docker Compose V2".

[image: Docker Desktop Settings]

For other typical problems you might run into, a few good community resources should be helpful:

- https://errorcotidianam.wordpress.com/2021/09/14/sitecore-docker-common-issues-on-installation/
- https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/100/developer-tools/troubleshooting-docker.html